# Can objdump use bss variable names in text section?

Tags: disassembly, objdump

I am using objdump to generate the disassembly of C code and wondering if there is a way to get the names of variables from the heap (.bss section) to be used in the .text section disassembly, rather than the hex addresses.

For example,

```
int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        request_ID = Receive(0, buffer, MSG_SIZE, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is compiled, and then using `objdump -D file.o` I get the disassembly, including the .bss section:

```
 400:   55                      push   ebp
 401:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 403:   83 ec 18                sub    esp,0x18
 ...
 43d:   a1 cc 24 00 00          mov    eax,ds:0x24cc

...
Disassembly of section .bss:

000024cc <request_pID>:
```

What I would like is for the hex addresses of variables to be replaced by their name:

```
     43d:   a1 cc 24 00 00          mov    eax, <request_pID>
```

I could write a sed script or something similar to achieve this, but was wondering if there was a simpler option.

Even better would be for both the address and the variable name to be printed to aid in debugging.

```
     43d:   a1 cc 24 00 00          mov    eax, ds:0x24cc <request_pID>
```

The code is for an operating system development being tested in Bochs, so if there is some other way of loading symbols into Bochs' debugger that would be a good workaround, although I would still like the objdump output to be created as well.

thanks, Paul